# Should file uploads in REST be their own resources?

Tags: rest, api, http, https

When implementing an API in a REST architecture. I could have a resource called Profile containing a users name and e-mail. Further I'd like the user to have a profile photo. Should this be part of the resource Profile or should it be its own resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the client would use the API. You could have:

```
/api/profile/{id}
```

which might return, for example:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Dave Smith",
  "email": "d.s@test.com"
}
```

and a separate photo API:

```
/api/profile/photo/{id}
```

could return a representation of the profile photo. REST is about representation so if you have the photo in its own endpoint, you can have different representations of it:

```
/api/profile/photo/{id}/small
/api/profile/photo/{id}/medium
/api/profile/photo/{id}/large
```

Having it as a separate call also means the client doesn't need to download it until it needs it. Also, being in its own endpoint you can update it without having to send unnecessary information to the server such as the profile data (name, email).

If you want to make it easy for the client to get the profile photo you could make use of [HATEOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) in the profile response:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Dave Smith",
  "email": "d.s@test.com",
  "links": [
    {
        "photo": "/api/profile/photo/1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

although it's debateable whether this is any use as the client would know how to get the profile photo anyway.

If your business model states that a profile must have a photo, to manage this with two endpoints, you'd need to upload the profile photo first, receive the id from the API in the return and create the new profile with that photo id:

```
POST /api/users
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "name": "Dave Smith",
      "email": "d.s@test.com",
      "photo": "4567"
    }
```

but your backend would need to prevent `DELETE` operations on profile photos if the profile they belonged to still existed.

Comment: What if I in the business model had defined that all profiles are required to have a profile photo?

How would I go about enforcing this with 2 resources?

Comment: I've added that info to the answer

Answer (score 1):

> When implementing an API in a REST architecture. I could have a resource called Profile containing a users name and e-mail. Further I'd like the user to have a profile photo. Should this be part of the resource Profile or should it be its own resource?

When you look at the web, I think you'll find in most cases that the profile resource and the profile image resource are different.  For example, on Twitter (as of 2019-07-23), the "profile image" is accessed using a different URI than the "profile" itself.  The HTML representation of the profile includes a *link* to the profile image.

That's approach is going to make a lot of sense if the profile and the profile image have different caching strategies.

In the case of twitter, for example, the profile changes *much* more frequently than the profile image does, so it makes sense to keep them separate.

Making the profile photo part of the same resource, I think, means either using the photo as an alternative *representation* of the resource, or *embedding* the image into the existing representation of the resource.  Both of those are fine for some purposes? but all other things being equal I wouldn't expect them to be better fit for purpose than using a separate resource instead.